# What's the simplest way to get an image to print in a new window when clicked?

Tags: javascript, url, browser, printing, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a simple click to print link for an image, and what I'd like to happen is when the link is clicked, a new window opens with the image, and the browser opens the print command dialogue box.

My question is whether this is possible just from a URL parameter, or from the anchor element on the initiating page? Or do I have to build a target page with javascript to do this?

Here's a sample of what I've got:

```
<p class="click-2-print">
  <a href="/img/map.jpg" target="_blank">Click here to print the map above</a>
</p>
```

Obviously the code above will open the image in a new window, but still requires to user to hit Ctrl+P, Cmd+P or use the browser commands. My client wants the image to "just print" when the user clicks the link, so I'm trying to find the simplest way to accomplish this.

So is there any parameters or attributes that I can add to the above markup to accomplish what I have described?

Answer (score 11):

You'll have to call window.print(). Perhaps something like this?

```
function printimage(){
    var URL = "http://myimage.jpg";

    var W = window.open(URL);

    W.window.print();
}
```

Another option may be to put the image on a page that tells the browser to print when loaded. For example...

```
<body onload="window.print();">
<img src="/img/map.jpg">
</body>
```

Comment: The first way didnt work for me. The window opened and tryed to print but because the image didnt load before the print action it previews nothing. I used something similar as the second way putting the image inside a page and waiting for it to load and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Cody Bonney's answer will not work in certain browsers if the full url includes the image extension. The browser will automatically download it as soon as the new tab opens. You can get around this like so.

```
                    var url = scope.src;
                    var w = window.open('', '');
                    w.document.write('<html><head>');
                    w.document.write('</head><body >');
                    w.document.write('<img id="print-image-element" src="'+url+'"/>');
                    w.document.write('<script>var img = document.getElementById("print-image-element"); img.addEventListener("load",function(){ window.focus(); window.print(); window.document.close(); window.close(); }); </script>');
                    w.document.write('</body></html>');
                    w.window.print();
```

This will open a new page with the image, prompt the user to print, and after printing, close the new tab and reset focus to the original tab.

Disregard the `scope.src` that is angular specific code. Everything else should work as long as you provide your own `url` value from somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you create a page in whatever language or framework you are working in that accepts a querystring argument for the image path, output that image in the document and have an `onload` / `ready` call to `window.print()`.  Link to that instead of the image directly, and keep the `target="_blank"` and you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [window.print()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) in javascript to trigger the browser print dialog. I'm pretty sure you can't trigger a print without user interaction unless you run a signed applet.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Jag. Although its not exactly what you are looking to do, I did write this tutorial while I was working at a web design firm. You can probably rummage that code to get the link that prints the image. Basically what this code does it add a print button to the fancybox jquery plugin. I dont see why you couldnt just use the print part to add it to whatever you need. Hope it helps.

[Add print ability to fancybox jquery plugin](http://www.thatagency.com/design-studio-blog/2010/04/add-print-ability-to-fancybox-jquery-plugin/)