# window.print image in a link

Tags: javascript, printing

So I have this:

```
<script>
   window.print();
</script>
```

I want to print this url's image:

```
http://www.somefancyurl.com/labels/postage/45029dd.png
```

The page displays nothing but the image I am wanting to print.

I tried:

```
<script>
   window.print('http://www.somefancyurl.com/labels/postage/45029dd.png');
</script>
```

But that didn't seem to change anything.

Thanks to some searching, I came up with this:

```
function printLabel(){

   popup = window.open();
   popup.document.write('<?php echo $order->shipmentLabel; ?>');
   popup.print();

   return false;
}
```

But that tries to print out `<?php echo $order->shipmentLabel; ?>` not the actual image.

Comment: In page, write html code like `<html><body><img src='http://www.somefancyurl.com/labels/postage/45029dd.png' /></body></html>` and write script

Comment: Would this help?

* [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073363/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-an-image-to-print-in-a-new-window-when-clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073363/whats-the-simplest-way-to-get-an-image-to-print-in-a-new-window-when-clicked)

Comment: @TamilSelvan Would you please put that in an answer, as it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In page, write html code like

```
<html>
<body>
<img src='http://www.somefancyurl.com/labels/postage/45029dd.png' />
</body>
</html>
```

and write script as

```
<script>
   window.print();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't print an image directly.

You should do it this way:

```
<script>
   window.print();
</script>
<img src="http://www.somefancyurl.com/labels/postage/45029dd.png" />
```

You can also do it in a new window.(popup)